# Xdebug not starting when use the XDEBUG_TRIGGER env on VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-remote

I'm configuring Xdebug in VS Code and it doesn't work when I use the `start_with_request=trigger` setting.
If I set the config value to `yes` it works.
I think VS Code is not sending the env variables from the `launch.json` file.

My Xdebug ini file:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger
```

My `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_TRIGGER": "true"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I use VSCode with Microsoft Remote-SSH extension on a Ubuntu VM and Windows 10.
My Xdebug extension is the XDebug official extension.

Log from Xdebug:

```
[2393] Log opened at 2022-03-29 13:54:04.173262
[2393] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[2393] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[2393] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_SESSION' not found, so not activating
[2393] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[2393] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[2393] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_SESSION' not found, so not activating
[2393] Log closed at 2022-03-29 13:54:04.360936
```

Comment: If you set `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=10`, that appears in the log?

Comment: @Derick I edited the question with the Xdebug logs.
I tried adding the `xdebug.trigger_value` setting but the result was the same.

Comment: That `xdebug.trigger_value` setting is for something else — but in this case you were right, something is not setting the environment variable. I don't know how to fix that, but you can (temporarily?) set `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` so that Xdebug tries to start a debugging session for every request.

Comment: I did this, but it was showing Xdebug error messages in the cli, so I disabled the module for cli.
Thanks, I will search by similar errors on VS Code and Windows to try find the solution.

Comment: @Lucas will it do any better if you add something like `"XDEBUG_CONFIG": "idekey=VSCODE"` in your `launch.json`? It worked for me for **local** debug when I tried PHP debug in VSCode (about a year ago). No ideas how it may work for a remote  one...

Comment: @LazyOne, that didn't work either.
But from my tests, it seems that VS Code is not loading the environment variables from the `env` property of the `launch.json` file.

Comment: @Derick I don't know who is responsible, VS Code or the PHP Debug extension, but could the environment variable be being added to my host (Windows) instead of the VM (Ubuntu)?

Comment: @Lucas I had to dig into my backups (as I do not use VSCode on a regular basis and for PHP debug I've only used it in that one project) to check how it was done there. And yes -- just as zobo said in his answer: it was not the "Listen for Xdebug" config entry but "Launch current script" one where VSCode launches the script and sets that env var. I should have double-checked that first instead of relying on my memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vscode-php-debug dev here.

This is a common misunderstanding. The provided `launch.json` only listens for Xdebug/DBGp connections - as the default name implies. If there was also a `program` setting in there, VS Code would also start a (php) process. And only in that case could VS Code contribute to the environment of that newly started process.

So, assuming you are running a web server, you can only change Xdebug settings by modifying the php.ini or somehow change the process environment of that web server process...

You can also check out other `launch.json` snippers by typing `php` at the end of the current snippet. Maybe some of them could be useful.

Perhaps I should add a warning if somebody sets `env` without setting `program`...

Comment: I tried using the 'Launch currently open script' setting, but it returns an error that it couldn't find a class within the file.
I'm going to use `start_with_request=yes`, as I've wasted a lot of time with that.
Thanks everyone for the replies.

Comment: @Lucas That is expected, especially for frameworks. If you call a certain Controller/etc directly then you are bypassing the whole framework bootstrap logic, where Composer autoloading is getting called.

Comment: @Lucas To debug web URLs you have to use either `start_with_request=yes` or Xdebug extension for your browser (that sets Xdebug cookie that acts as a "debug me" flag -- standard thing; can also use GET/POST parameter for that, check the docs). But if you debug a CLI script (or if your framework is good and can call web controllers via CLI) then you should provide all the needed script params in your separate launch.json config entry (VSCode should be able to do this -- PhpStorm can). The idea is -- you are calling your entry point index.php that routes the request further.